# Calculate the number of elements to cover an area within a specific distance

Tags: area

What is the minimum number of items we need to place in an area of 10000m2 and a distance of 5 meters with the whole area covered?

Comment: It depends on what the items are. It could anywhere from one to infinitely many. You'll need to better explain what you want.

Comment: So you want to cover the region with radius-5 circles. Are we allowed to determine the shape of the region, or is it maybe a square of side length 100?

Comment: @RobPratt he didn't mention circles.

Comment: The shape of the region doesn't really matter, but the maximum distance between the items shouldn't be greater than 5 meters [or exactly 5 meters to make it easier]

Comment: Is this your [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216211/what-is-the-optimal-solution-for-covering-a-rectangle-with-circles/216950#216950) ?

Comment: Then you might do best if the overall region to be covered is a circle: https://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/circovcir/

Comment: @almagest I don't think so no. Let me explain the question again with more detail.                                                                                                             
Given an area of interest A with surface |A| 10,000 m2, assume we deploy wireless sensor motes with communication range 5 [metres]; the motes are deployed over the area uniformly at random and independently from each other. What is the minimum number of sensors we need to deploy in order to establish a connected wireless sensor network with high probability?